# Mocking class with existing class in JMockit (replacement for `redefineMethods`)

Tags: java, class, mocking, jmockit

I've got two classes as input and want to mock one with the other.  That used to be very simple in JMockit, one just called

```
Mockit.redefineMethods(originalClass, mockingClass);
```

But in version 0.999 this deprecated method was removed.  I need features of a newer version of JMockit, so I cannot use the older versions any more.

I guess from the documentation in the deprecation message that using the proposed "modern" way to do it would be to define a `MockUp<originalClass>` and use this as the `mockingClass`.

Unfortunately, I get both values as input parameters at runtime (declared as `class<?>`), so creating a class is not an option.

Is there any way to emulate what `Mockit.redefineMethods()` has done before version 0.999, even if it might be not the most elegant solution to address this issue?

EDIT

What I get as input is a `Map<Class<?>, Class<?>> mockedClasses` of classes to be mocked pointing to classes mocking them.  These are then iterated over and passed to `Mockit`:

```
for (Map.Entry<Class<?>, Class<?>> entry : mockedClasses.entrySet()) {
  Mockit.redefineMethods(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
}
```

After that, the test code is executed, then the mocking is disabled again, using `restoreOriginalDefinition()` instead of `redefineMethods()` in a similar way.

Comment: Not sure this is what you need, but there is a `MockUp(Class)` constructor which receives the class to be mocked. Otherwise, I would need to see an example test, because `MockUp` provides everything that `Mockit.redefineMethods` did in the past.

Comment: Thanks, I will try that tomorrow.  And if I don't succeed I will try to cook down a minimal example and post that here.

Comment: On second thought, no, that's not working for me, sorry.  I already *have* both classes, the one to be mocked and the mocking one.  Both are arbitrary and my input (and I cannot easily change that).  None of them (currently) is extending `MockUp`, and I cannot extend the class I receive as a value with a `MockUp` (at least I don't know how).  But maybe there are solutions going that way?

Comment: @Rogério, I added a small part showing a little more explicit code on what I am doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, the question is clearer now. And the answer is that there is no way to mock a class with another arbitrary class; you have to define the mock-up class as a subclass of `MockUp`. The very old `Mockit.redefineMethods(Class, Class)` (removed from the API 4.5+ years ago) only accepted arbitrary classes because that initial API also supported Java 1.4 for test code (which is no longer supported since 0.999, which required generics and/or annotations).

Comment: This makes it a problem for me as my legacy code is depending on this removed feature in a very fundamental way.  I fear we are going to lose test cases now or have to update each of them manually.  But thanks anyway!